# What value of a makes this function continuous

Tags: calculus

Note that $a \ne 0$.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{2x} & \text{if $x \ne 0$} \\ 3a-1 & \text{if $x=0$} \end{cases}$$

I believe if we want to find a value of a, we need to equate both equations to eachother and solve for a. When doing this, we need to also substitute $x=0$ and solve.

However, I don't like what I achieve with this logic: 
$$sin(ax) = 2x(3a-1)$$
$$sin(a(0)) = 2(0)(3a-1)$$

And it doesn't matter what value of a is at this point. How do I approach this problem appropriately then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{\sin ax}{2x}=\frac a2\cdot\frac{\sin ax}{ax}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}\frac a2\cdot1$$

Comment: Nice hint.  (+1)

Comment: Coming back to this problem, why is it that the denominator becomes $ax$ now?

Comment: @user382540 it doesn't "become": I multiplied by $\;a\;$ **but also** divided by $\;a\;$ the whole expression